# How do I loop through cells in a specific column and delete the entire row based on its contents?

Tags: excel, vba

This is another question where I feel like there's a simple answer, but I'm not finding it.  I'm looping through each cell in column D and looking for specific dates (from the user input) and based on that cell's date and the dates in some corresponding cells, I'm changing the color of the row.

Instead of coloring the row, I'd like to be able to delete it.

Here's my code that currently colors those rows:

```vb
Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Select

Dim rCell, otherCell As Range
Dim TheAnswer$
Dim ConvertedDate#

TheAnswer = InputBox("In M/D/YY format, enter the first day of the month for which this report is being run." & _
                     vbCr & vbCr & "For example, you would enter ""12/1/2012"" for the December 2012 report.", "Enter Date M/D/YY")
ConvertedDate = CDate(TheAnswer)

For Each rCell In Selection
    If rCell.Value <> "" Then
        If rCell.Value And rCell.Offset(, 5) < ConvertedDate And rCell.Offset(, 5) <> "" Then rCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)

        If rCell.Value < ConvertedDate And rCell.Offset(, 5) = "" Then

            If rCell.Offset(, 6) < ConvertedDate And rCell.Offset(, 6) <> "" Then rCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)

            If rCell.Offset(, 7) < ConvertedDate And rCell.Offset(, 7) <> "" Then rCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)

        End If

    End If
Next rCell
```

When I substitute `rCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)` with `rCell.EntireRow.Delete` I get errors.  If I step through the code I can see that it actually does delete the first row, but then errors out at the next line.

I obviously have multiple "If Then" statements, but if the first "If Then" condition is satisfied and the row is deleted, it should move on to the next cell.  It seems to me that it's still trying to check that row that's been deleted.  I'm definitely not an Excel VBA expert, but I'm thinking there should be something to add after the `rCell.EntireRow.Delete` piece that tells it to move to the next cell.  I tried adding in `Next rCell`, but that errors out.  `Exit For` just stops the macro altogether.

Comment: It would be useful to see your data in more detail. An efficient way to delete rows (manually or with VBA) is to set up an Boolean IF test on each row returning TRUE or FALSE, if the condition(s) to delete are met, then using `Autofilter` to delete the met conditions. Range loops can be very slow

Comment: There's nothing special about my spreadsheet.  It's basically just a list of dates in columns D-K.  I'm not familiar with `Autofilter` so I guess I'll have to look into that.  As you can see from my code above, my original approach was to change the row color.  I was also thinking I could also (or alternatively) add something to one of the cells and then delete all the rows whose cell had that added thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below, I updated and changed some duplicate conditions. The best two ways are either add the data into a variant array, process and then delete or as brettdj mentions in the comment add a flag, filter and then mass delete. I prefer the below as it scales well and is good practise to know for other data manipulation. Not tested as no template to base it on. See below:

```
Dim data() As Variant
Dim i As Double
Dim deleteRows As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim theAnswer As String
Dim ConvertedDate As Date

Set sht = Sheet1

theAnswer = InputBox("In M/D/YY format, enter the first day of the month for which this report is being run." & _
                 vbCr & vbCr & "For example, you would enter ""12/1/2012"" for the December 2012 report.", "Enter Date M/D/YY")
ConvertedDate = CDate(theAnswer)

data = sht.Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 8)

    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)

        If (data(i, 1) <> vbNullString) Then

            If data(i, 1) <> vbNullString And data(i, 6) < ConvertedDate And data(i, 6) <> vbNullString Then

                If (deleteRows Is Nothing) Then
                    Set deleteRows = sht.Rows(i + 1)
                Else
                    Set deleteRows = Union(deleteRows, sht.Rows(i + 1))
                End If

            ElseIf data(i, 1) < ConvertedDate And data(i, 7) <> vbNullString And data(i, 8) <> vbNullString Then

                If data(i, 7) < ConvertedDate Or data(i, 8) < ConvertedDate Then

                    If (deleteRows Is Nothing) Then
                        Set deleteRows = sht.Rows(i + 1)
                    Else
                        Set deleteRows = Union(deleteRows, sht.Rows(i + 1))
                    End If

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Next i

deleteRows.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Philip, but I can't get your code to work either.  The first thing I noticed is that there's an `End If` missing, but even if I add one in, I get a Run-time error (Object variable or With block variable not set) on the line for `deleteRows = Sheet1.rows(i + 1)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but now it's not even doing anything.  I thought maybe it had something to do with the `Sheet1` part (since that isn't the name of the tab on what I'm using to test), but changing that only broke it.  If I step through the code, it seems to be working, as it reacts to the various "If Then" statements differently (even though I see nothing happening on the spreadsheet), but it ends up doing nothing.  Is the final step correct?  Or in the right spot?

I know you said you can't test it, but there's nothing special about my spreadsheet... really just a list of dates in columns D-K.

Comment: tested and updated the code in what I believe to be your layout. Replace Set sht = Sheet1 with your sheet.

Comment: The name of the sheet I'm testing on is **Export** but when I used that instead of **Sheet1** I got an error.  However, I'd like it to be more universal and not contingent upon the name of the sheet, so I tried `ActiveSheet` instead and that worked perfectly.  Honestly, it ran instantaneously.  All the other ones I've been trying take time to loop through.

Comment: good to hear. Adding the values into a variant array is always faster than looping over each cell in the sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Mike, when you loop through range sets and delete rows, you need to loop backward from the last row because when you delete a row it doesn't exist anymore and it throughs Excel because that row is no longer in the loop range.

Try this:

```
Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Select

Dim rCell as Range, otherCell As Range
Dim TheAnswer$
Dim ConvertedDate#

TheAnswer = InputBox("In M/D/YY format, enter the first day of the month for which this report is being run." & _
                     vbCr & vbCr & "For example, you would enter ""12/1/2012"" for the December 2012 report.", "Enter Date M/D/YY")
ConvertedDate = CDate(TheAnswer)

Dim xrows as Long, i as Long
xrows = Selection.Rows.Count

For i = xrows to 1 Step -1

    Set rCell = Selection.Cells(i,1)

    If rCell.Value <> "" Then
        If rCell.Value And rCell.Offset(, 5) < ConvertedDate And rCell.Offset(, 5) <> "" Then rCell.EntireRow.Delete

        If rCell.Value < ConvertedDate And rCell.Offset(, 5) = "" Then

            If rCell.Offset(, 6) < ConvertedDate And rCell.Offset(, 6) <> "" Then rCell.EntireRow.Delete

            If rCell.Offset(, 7) < ConvertedDate And rCell.Offset(, 7) <> "" Then rCell.EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    End If

Next i
```

Not sure if you wanted all to be `EntireRow.Delete`, but you can easily switch it back.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Scott, but I can't get your code to work.  If I try it as is, I get a compile error "Duplicate declaration in current scope" which points to the line `Dim rows as Long, i as Long`.  If I use a different word than "rows" (like xrows), I don't get a compile error,  but I do get an error that says I have a type mismatch on the next line when I try to run it.

Comment: @Mike. You probably have a variable declared as `rows` somewhere else in your code. If that's the case, you can either change all my references to `xrows`, as you started to do, but you need to carry it through to all times it's used. So `Dim xrows as Long`, `xrows = Selection.Rows`, `For i = xrows to 1 Step -1`. Otherwise it will keep referring to your original rows declaration, which may not jive with what I did.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought might be the problem because when I tried to change it to a capital **R** anywhere, it kept changing back on me.  Problem is, I couldn't find it anywhere.  I even did a search for **row** for the whole project and came up with nothing.  Is there some global place I should be looking to see if that declaration exists?

Also, I did carry that `xrows` name through (luckily, I knew that much), but still got that error on the next line - `xrows = Selection.rows`.  I'm now thinking this row declaration that I can't find is messing that up as well.

Comment: @Mike -> oops, i goofed. The line should read 'Selection.Rows.Count` I forgot to add the `Count` method which returns the count of the rows. The mismatch is because the `Rows` property signifies an `Range` Object, where as `xrows` is set to a `Long` variable. I edited the answer as such. Sorry about that ... Also, it's best to avoid declaring variables with the same name as built-in properties / methods. That may be another reason XL didn't like the captial R...

Comment: OK, that helps, so thank you... but it now it doesn't appear to do anything.  I added a `MsgBox` into the loop so I could see that it was looking in the correct cells and I noticed that even though it appears to be looping, it's actually checking the last row over and over and over.  Honestly, I'm a little surprised it doesn't put me in an infinite loop when it runs.

Comment: @Mike I'd get an F for attention to detail on this answer ...  this line `Set rCell = Selection.Cells(xrows,1)` should say `Set rCell = Selection.Cells(i,1)` as you should iterate through i, not xrows

Comment: That's OK, Scott.  I appreciate your help and persistence. Unfortunately, I don't think it'll ever work (for the same reason I couldn't get my initial code to work). As soon as the first condition is met and a row is deleted, the next condition hits a roadblock - the `rcell` it's trying to check is now gone. I have a couple ideas for a workaround (such as rewrite the "If Then" statements to include a bunch of `ElseIf` conditions... or have it go to a bookmark in the code that skips the rest of the checking of that row), but it seems pointless when Philip's solution above is nearly perfect.

Comment: OK, so apparently that second idea I had did work.  After each of the three parts where it deletes the row `rCell.EntireRow.Delete`, I added the following step `GoTo JumpAhead` (of course, followed by `End If` since it doesn't remain on one line like we had previously).  Then, I added a simple `JumpAhead:` right before the last `End If` in the loop.  This does work now, but it takes a good amount of time to run.

Comment: @Mike -> Yeah, that sounds like a bit of a hack solution...  an array based solution is definitely better for speed, usually, however, in general stepping back through lines instead of forward usually always works when deleting rows because you will always have the next row back in your loop.